# Two cron jobs connecting to same database simultaneously causes connection failure

Tags: oracle, cron, pentaho

I have two data ETL jobs (Pentaho) scheduled via cron tab. One runs every 5 minutes and the other runs every hour. Both jobs try to connect to the same database. When there is an overlap on the running time of these jobs, one of the jobs fails and the log shows "Error occurs connecting to database". Can anyone share some thoughts about the potential root cause of this issue?

Comment: maybe a timeout due to a long running transaction from the already running job? Do both jobs modify the same tables?

Comment: Is it important that they are started by cron or just that they are started sumultaneously? If not, remove that tag!

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek to your question, they don't query the same table.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for the reply. That's a good suggestion. I noticed the issue because these jobs are triggered by cron. Maybe I can try to run them at same time to see if cron tab matters.

Comment: @nkgxgongxi maybe a session limitation on the database? Do you really get a connection timeout or is there an ORA-message somewhere down the line? ORA-02391 for instance would suggest that there's a user limit that has been reached. You could also look into the oracle trace logs to see if there's anything right about the time the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

It is not generally a good idea to synchronize ETL based on time. We had a lot of problems with table locking, truncate or delete record just after creation, ETL starting before the previous finishes correctly, etc, etc.

With Pentaho, you can write a job to orchestrate the run transformations.

In your case, I would write one job that run every 5 minutes, executes the first transformation and, once over 12 times runs the second transformation.

An other way of doing this to run the two jobs that may fail as sub-job of a main job. After the sub-job, you can catch the error, wait 6 or 7 minutes and try to restart again. If you do that put a counter in order to limit the restarts to 4 or 5, and send you a mail in case of successive failures.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I think the issue is that these two jobs have different business meanings, so it would be hard to maintain both of them in one Pentaho job. Also, both of them don't write to the DB but just try to query data.

Comment: I did mean maintain the two jobs in one. Rather, I was thinking about writing a super job whose responsibility is to run the other two, after checking there will be no synchronization issues.